# Code Coverage possible for TFS Build 2008 building Visual Studio 2010 Project?

Tags: tfs, build-automation, code-coverage, tfsbuild

We have moved to Visual Studio 2010 but our TFS folks are not ready yet.  After some work, we can get the build to work, but we don't get code coverage.

We are running using the MSTest test runner.  Does anyone know any tricks to get TFS to report code coverage using Visual Studio 2010 on a build server that has a TFS 2008 Build agent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is command line tool that name is VsPerfMon.
Whit this tool you can run your code coverage via command line. You can check this link for more information, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182404(VS.80).aspx

So if you can run code coverage via command line, you can invoke this tool via TFS 2008 Build Scripts.